# Alt +Tab behaviour in Gnome

Tags: gnome, keyboard-shortcuts, window-manager

It may be a silly question but in Windows I used <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> to switch back between my open windows, that is go back to previous windows.

Unfortunately, it is not working in Gnome. I have even used <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd><kbd>Left</kbd> but with no success.

So how can I do the same in Gnome on RHEL6?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like something potentially with your keyboard or your installation. I use both of the following in Gnome:

- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to cycle from left to right
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to cycle from right to left

This [article is Ubuntu specific but should be applicable](https://web.archive.org/web/20150827061822/http://linuxers.org/quick-tips/enable-alt-shift-tab-ubuntu) to your situation on RHEL6 non the less.

#### gconf-editor

Double check that the preferences are set so that moving right to left is configured correctly for the key combo mentioned above:

[image: ss of gconf-editor]

Comment: It was disabled there, I made it <Alt><Shift>Tab, but still it didn't work. I changed the keyboard layout (language) switch shortcut from Alt+Shift to Ctrl+Shift as were suggested in the comments in the link you provided, I don't know how they can be related but it started to work.

Comment: And now, ironically enough, ctrl+shift+tab to switch back between browser's tabs stopped to work :)

Answer (score 8):

For anyone using **GNOME v3**, here's what I have done.

I am using vanilla GNOME 3 on Ubuntu 18.04 (that is installing the base version of GNOME not the Ubuntu modified version). I think vanilla GNOME is the same as what RHEL uses too - at least that's what Fedora uses, so the following should work across those systems.

GNOME has two concepts for tabbing - tabbing between **applications** (the default) and tabbing between **windows**. Tabbing between applications groups the windows for that application together. I prefer (or at least I am more used to) tabbing between windows (and combined with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to go backwards).

In GNOME 3 at least this can now be fixed by just configuring the keyboard shortcuts.

1. Go to the regular Settings > Devices > Keyboard > Navigation section.
2. Disable both 'Switch applications' and 'Switch windows'
3. Now neither <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> nor <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> should work. Possibly do a log out/restart in between (I can't remember)
4. Re-enable 'Switch windows' to be **Alt+Tab**.

I found that if both 'Switch applications' and 'Switch windows' were enabled then somehow Alt+Tab would still end up switching applications. This at least should be a solid method for guaranteeing that the Alt+Tab works as expected. You can then experiment setting 'Switch applications to **Super+Tab**.

This is what my keyboard shortcut settings looks like, note the 'Switch applications' at the top and 'Switch windows' at the bottom:

[image]

Comment: This is helpful. Thanks. Just to add, I made a switch on gnome 3.32.2 (RHEL 8.3) without logout/restart and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in Debian Stretch, Gnome 3.22.2.

Following similar steps mentioned in previous answer by user @icc97

1. Go to the regular Settings > Devices > Keyboard > Navigation section.
2. Setting Switch Windows of an application to <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> (it disables Switch Applications)

Worked for me.

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank your for your contribution. You may want to add instructions on where/how to apply this setting so that your answer is helpful to as many users as possible.